# What is the diff version git uses? diff2 or diff3?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

Does anyone know which diff version is used by git?

[This article](http://fabiensanglard.net/git_code_review/diff.php) for example explains in detail the diff algorithm for dummies but what is the actual algorithm which is used?

For general knowledge here are the specs for [`diff2`](http://www.xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf) and [`diff3`](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/papers/diff3-short.pdf).

I know you can configure git to use `diff2` or `diff3`

```
git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the [config documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):
git defaults is diff2

> `merge.conflictStyle`
>
> Specify the style in which conflicted hunks are written out to working tree files upon merge.
>
> The default is "merge", which shows a <<<<<<< conflict marker,
>     changes made by one side, a ======= marker,
>     changes made by the other side,
>     and then a >>>>>>> marker. An alternate style,
>
> "diff3", adds a ||||||| marker and the original text before the ======= marker.

Comment: No, despite it being the alternative to `diff3`, it's not called `diff2`, it's called `merge`.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be confusing 3 different things

1. The unix command line tool `diff3` provided by [GNU diffutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/)
2. The output format of the diff that git provides (in which `diff3` is a non-default option)
3. The algorithm that git uses to generate the diff

Git supports 4 different diff algorithms.

You can specify via the command line to `git diff`

```
  --minimal
       Spend extra time to make sure the smallest possible diff is produced.

   --patience
       Generate a diff using the "patience diff" algorithm.

   --histogram
       Generate a diff using the "histogram diff" algorithm.

   --diff-algorithm={patience|minimal|histogram|myers}
       Choose a diff algorithm. The variants are as follows:
   default, myers
       The basic greedy diff algorithm. Currently, this is the default.

   minimal
       Spend extra time to make sure the smallest possible diff is produced.

   patience
       Use "patience diff" algorithm when generating patches.

   histogram
       This algorithm extends the patience algorithm to "support low-occurrence common elements".
```

or via git configuration.

```
  diff.algorithm
   Choose a diff algorithm. The variants are as follows:

   default, myers
       The basic greedy diff algorithm. Currently, this is the default.

   minimal
       Spend extra time to make sure the smallest possible diff is produced.

   patience
       Use "patience diff" algorithm when generating patches.

   histogram
       This algorithm extends the patience algorithm to "support low-occurrence common elements".
```

The `diff2` pdf-link in your original question is a description of the `myers` algorithm, and seems to be unrelated to the 2-way conflict markers git calls `diff2` in `merge.conflictStyle`.

Similarly, the unix tool `diff3` is unrelated to the 3-way conflict markers git calls `diff3`.

Comment: Andrew where are you working in HPE? im working there as well.

Comment: How can I generate a similar output given by git at merge conflicts? Is there such a tool in GNU tools or anywhere else?